# How to construct likelihood ratio tests when the null hypothesis is of this form?

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

For example, I know how to get the likelihood ratio when $H_o: \theta = 3$ against $H_1: \theta > 3$. We derive some rule involving $x$ and a constant from the likelihood ratio, and then find the probability of type I error. But when the null hypothesis is of the form $H_o: \theta \leq 3$, how do I do this? Assume that $X$ is from an exponential distribution with mean $\frac{1}{\theta}$ and I have to construct a LRT with $\alpha=0.05$.

Answer (score 1):

$H_0=3$ and $H_0\leq 3$ are equivalent. This because of the definition of $\alpha$

$$\alpha= \sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} \pi(\theta)$$

where $\pi(\theta)$ is the power function

thus if you know how to verify this system

$$\begin{cases}
H_0: \theta=3\\
H_1: \theta>3
\end{cases}$$

verify this one in the same way.

$$\begin{cases}
H_0: \theta\leq3\\
H_1: \theta>3
\end{cases}$$

in an informal way: The null hypotesis is always considered TRUE until you have enough data to reject it...thus you assume as $H_0$ the best value you can choose...so if $H_0$ is $\theta \leq 3$ you choose $\theta=3$ as the best value to be verified

If your model belongs to the exponential family (as it is the example you posted) this test is well explained [here, on page 422, theorem 5](https://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/446/Introduction%20to%20the%20theory%20of%20statistics%20by%20MOOD.pdf)

If you read next page, 423 the example 13 is exactly yours! What the book does not state is that the resulting integral can be solved via chi-squared distribution, but I think you perfectly know that.

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes sense now. Yes I can move ahead with the problem now.